# how check font-family on js?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, fonts

Possible check user is install font family, if is not install run js function application use angular js
I use typekit font. I have load font this service only user without this font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the js file discussed at http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/.

It relies on two principles: 

  1. Different fonts have different character widths.

  2. If you try to use a font that's not installed in your browser, it will use a default font instead.

So if you want to test if font F is installed, the basic idea is to create an element with some text using font F. Then create the same element and text using the default browser font. Then compare the widths of the two elements using the offsetWidth property. If they are the same, it is very likely that F isn't supported by your browser. If they are different, F must be supported by your browser.